# Launch screen storyboard with multiple scenes

Tags: ios, xcode7, launch-screen

I read somewhere that it's possible to have multiple scenes in launch screen storyboard.  How are the other scenes used?

Comment: "If you are using a storyboard you can specify multiple view controllers but there are again some limitations. For example you can embed view controllers in a navigation or tab bar controller but more complex container classes such as UISplitViewController do not work (at least not yet)." source: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard.html

Comment: Thanks - I know this article.  It doesn't explain how multiple view controllers are used given a launch screen only involves one screen.

Comment: I don't have any official source regarding your setup, but I know you can't even assign a custom `UIViewController` subclass or implement any logic (code) -app launch should be as lightweight as possible, only static views.

Comment: If you are looking to use different view controllers depending on screen size, perhaps auto-layout and size classes is your ticket. If you wish to show a separate launch screen based on some other condition, I have little hope...